# xslt test if an attribute exist

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this following xslt. I notice that sometimes the element name 'tuple' has an attribute. I want to remove the attribute and add it as an Element. I added **a test** to verify if 'tuple' has an attribute but it returns a blank 'ecatalogue' element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="atom">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--this test doesn't work properly -->
    <xsl:template match="tuple">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@name">
             <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- nothing to do
            the node should stay the same
        -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- end test -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result I had with this template above.

```
<ecatalogue>

</ecatalogue>
```

https://gist.github.com/guinslym/5ce47460a31fe4c4046b

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a sample source XML file, and what you want it to transform to.

Comment: Thanks Mitch! my gist link didn't work...

Comment: @PapoucheGuinslyzinho will the attribute always be `@name`, can't it have another name?

Comment: @lingamurthy-cs not necessarly. It's just that when I converted the orginal xml to json. It looked messy (tuple>table>tuple...)  so I wanted to transfert it with xslt to have a simplier version that I can convert to json. (name>data_content). matthias_h's solution is great but if you have an other solution you  can still post. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I notice that sometimes the element name 'tuple' has an attribute. I
>   want to remove the attribute and add it as an Element. I added a test
>   to verify if 'tuple' has an attribute

This is definitely **not** the best approach when working with XSLT. You want to transform the attribute, not its parent `tuple` element - so your template should match the attribute *directly*, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="tuple/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

No tests are required here: if the attribute exists, the template will match it and process it; if not, the template will not be applied at all.

--

Note: the above is assuming you want to transform the attribute into a child element of `tuple`, sibling to the other, already existing, children.Your post is not quite clear on that point.

Answer (score 2):

With the following adjustments to your template matching `tuple`

```
<xsl:template match="tuple">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@name">
      <tuple>
        <xsl:element name="{@name}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </tuple>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

all `tuple` nodes without a `name` attribute are copied:

```
<xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

and in case a `tuple` has a `name` attribute, the `tuple` is written without an attribute, the attribute added as element (without any value as it's not clear if it should have any value) and the child nodes copied:

```
<xsl:when test="@name">
  <tuple>
    <xsl:element name="{@name}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </tuple>
</xsl:when>
```

Part of the input XML as example:

```
<tuple name="ObjManufacturerRef">
  <NamOrganisation>Unknown;:;Inconnu</NamOrganisation>
  <NamOrganisationAcronym>Unknown</NamOrganisationAcronym>
  <AddPhysCountry>Unknown</AddPhysCountry>
</tuple>
```

results in:

```
<tuple>
  <ObjManufacturerRef/>
  <NamOrganisation>Unknown;:;Inconnu</NamOrganisation>
  <NamOrganisationAcronym>Unknown</NamOrganisationAcronym>
  <AddPhysCountry>Unknown</AddPhysCountry>
</tuple>
```

Saved example: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQq/1 with an added `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to remove whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @matthias_h for the answer. I will modify it so that it will output : tuple>ObjManufacturerRef>children[nameOr...NameOr..AddPhy]. thanks for xsltransform.net I didn't know that website.